# Angular - Stream multiple HTTP calls 2 per 2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an array of payload elements: `[1,2,3,4]`.
I would like to stream the payload over multiple HTTP calls, 2 HTTP calls simultaneously.

Fire the first 2 HTTP calls, the first one with paylaodElement[0] and the second with paylaodElement[1]. Wait for the result, then make 2 new HTTP calls...

here's a code that fires all payloads on multiple calls simultaneously:

```
const streams = [].concat.apply(
  [],
  payload.map((el) => this.http.get(API_ENDPOINT, { el }))
);
```

Then:

```
forkJoin(streams).subscribe(result => {
 // 
})
```

This fire N HTTP call, where, N = `payload.length`.
How can we chunk this by only 2 calls simultaneously?

Comment: the question kind of not enough understandable, can you please rewrite the scenario once again ?

Comment: @Midhun I have an array of users, I would like to make one HTTP call for each user (to save it with a POST). This works with the code on the question. Now I would like to save 2 users at once, so make 2 HTTP calls simultaneously

Comment: OK got it , so what you are trying to do is ultimately you need to sent N HTTP POST requests, while 2 at a time. am i right ?

Comment: @Midhun exactly! 2 per 2 ...

Comment: did you work with bufferCount from rxjs, i think it works fine for your case, only thing is add a unique id to request if you want to process differently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question right I would proceed like this

```
// first use the from rxjs function to turn an array into a stream of its values
from(payload).pipe(
   // then with bufferCount create a stream of tuples
   bufferCount(2),
   // now we have a stream of tuples - we turn the element of each tuple into 
   // a tuple of http calls using the map operator
   // consider that the inner map is the map function of the javascript array 
   // while the outer map is the rxjs operator
   map(tuple => tuple.map(t => this.http.get(API_ENDPOINT, { el })),
   // now we fire the calls in parallel using forkJoin
   // we use concatMap to say "wait until forkJoin notifies its result
   // before firing the next tuple of calls
   concatMap(tupleOfHttpCalls => forkJoin(tupleOfHttpCalls))
)
.subscribe(tupleOfResults => {
   // here you do whatever you want with the tuple of results
})
```

While this code should do what you are looking for, I would consider also a solution where you limit the number of parallel calls to 2 but do not create tuple, rather you have a continuous stream, i.e. when 2 calls are on flight and the first one completes, you immediately start a new one.

Such solution would look like this

```
// first use the from rxjs function to turn an array into a stream of its values
from(payload).pipe(
   // then we use mergeMap with the concurrent value (the second parameter) to limit
   // concurrency to 2
   mergeMap(value => this.http.get(API_ENDPOINT, { el }), 2),
)
.subscribe(result => {
   // here you do whatever you want with each single result
})
```

[This blog](https://medium.com/p/ef636c9af19a) can provide you some more ideas about rxjs patterns to be used with asynchronous calls.